# How to print specific object keys using jq?

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I want to do a really simple thing using **jq** and I can't.

The object is:

```
{
  "DomainStatus": {
    "DomainId": "12345",
    "DomainName": "test",
    "ARN": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:12345:domain/test",
    "Created": true,
    "Deleted": false,
    "Endpoint": "test.com",
    "Processing": false,
    "UpgradeProcessing": false,
    "ElasticsearchVersion": "5.3",
    "ElasticsearchClusterConfig": {
      "InstanceType": "t2.medium.elasticsearch",
      "InstanceCount": 2,
      "DedicatedMasterEnabled": false,
      "ZoneAwarenessEnabled": true,
      "ZoneAwarenessConfig": {
        "AvailabilityZoneCount": 2
      }
    },
    "EBSOptions": {
      "EBSEnabled": true,
      "VolumeType": "gp2",
      "VolumeSize": 30
    },
... more fields ...
  }
}
```

And I want any of these options:

Option 1:

```
{
  "DomainName": "test",
  "Endpoint": "test.com",
  "ElasticsearchClusterConfig": {
    "InstanceType": "t2.medium.elasticsearch",
    "InstanceCount": 2,
  }
}
```

OR

Option 2:

```
{
  "DomainName": "test",
  "Endpoint": "test.com",
  "InstanceType": "t2.medium.elasticsearch",
  "InstanceCount": 2,
}
```

I achieved Option 2 using:

`jq '.DomainStatus | {DomainName, Endpoint, InstanceType: .ElasticsearchClusterConfig.InstanceType, InstanceCount: .ElasticsearchClusterConfig.InstanceCount}'`

BUT the problem is that **I don't want to write redundant code**.

I don't want this line: `InstanceType: .ElasticsearchClusterConfig.InstanceType`

It want something like this: `.ElasticsearchClusterConfig | {InstanceType, InstanceCount}` inside the **jq** command I wrote before.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: No, I need the full command. Your answer works, but it doesn't work inside the full jq command I wrote.

Comment: What do you mean? The example JSON you posted does not contain DomainStatus. Include it and I’ll update  my answer

Comment: The full command is  jq '.ElasticsearchClusterConfig |= {InstanceType, InstanceCount}'. That's the entire command. What else do you want given the input json you provided?

Comment: OMG! I'm sorry. I updated the question and included the full JSON.

Comment: @Kkk: I've updated my answer below

Comment: @Inian Thanks to you, today I learned something important for the rest of my life: "I should not simplify the real problem when I ask a question". Now, I understand the comment from reegnz. I "assumed" that you understood that the input is a real object from a "AWS elasticsearch domain". It is a bigger object than the "simplified" object I wrote. I updated again the source object, so you could fully understand what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Kkk: Did the answer work out for you now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to repeat any code. You can instruct `jq` to keep only the fields you want. The `|=`, assignment update operator modifies the object to its left, by recreating it with fields on its right. In our case, only update the ones you need.

```
.DomainStatus | { 
    DomainName, 
    Endpoint, 
    ElasticsearchClusterConfig: (
       .ElasticsearchClusterConfig | { 
           InstanceType, 
           InstanceCount 
       }
    )
}
```

[option 1 - jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/K64Ra4idUM)

or option 2, if you don't want to type out the names explicitly, use a placeholder like

```
.DomainStatus | .ElasticsearchClusterConfig as $ec | { 
    DomainName, 
    Endpoint, 
    InstanceType:  $ec.InstanceType, 
    InstanceCount: $ec.InstanceCount
}
```

[option 2 - jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/XkJAGrglPG)